# Copy worksheet to new workbook and change the name of the worksheet to a compose name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm copying a lot of workbooks to 1 workbook, but since all the worksheets on the different workbook have the same name, and each workbook have the name of the file on B1, so I want to name the new sheet as "violation(name)"

These is the code I have for that part

```
Dim wc As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SheetNewName As String
Dim Parname As String
Dim SheetName As String

Select Case wc.Cells(n, 1)
    Case "PK"
        SheetName = "Peak"
    Case "Sfactor"
        SheetName = "SF Supply"
    Case Else
        SheetName = wc.Cells(n, 1)
End Select

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Violations Summary")
Set Parname = wc.Range("B1")
Set SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set lastsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count).Select
lastsheet.Name = SheetNewName
```

I get the an error when trying to change the name of the new sheet on the new workbook, error is

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

On these line

```
Set SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"
```

But if I modify the code to be like these

```
Set Parname = wc.Range("B1")
Set SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set lastsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
lastsheet.Name = Parname
```

It copy the sheet, but dosen't change the name and get error

> Run time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Is there a question being asked? SheetName doesn't exist so you can't set SheetNewName to it &.... unless it appears somewhere else in the code before?

Comment: Did you mean to use part of  the string from wc.Name?

Comment: yes sheetname exist, idint put the code for it

Select Case wc.Cells(n, 1)

                    Case "PK"
                       SheetName = "Peak"
                    Case "Sfactor"
                        SheetName = "SF Supply"
                    Case Else
                       SheetName = wc.Cells(n, 1)
                    End Select

Comment: Are you receiving an error? This code looks similar to  previous post where the solution involved using the Worksheets collection not sheets

Comment: Yes is the same code, but now i get the an error when trying to change the name of the new sheet on the new workbook, error is Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Which line of code does this occur at?

Comment: Revise your question to include the error you're getting if any and why you believe your code is not working.

Comment: It seems that is on these Set SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `"SET"` as string variable:

```
Set SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"
```

Needs to be modified to

```
SheetNewName = SheetName & "(" & Parname & ")"
```

and

```
Set Parname = wc.Range("B1")
```

needs to be

```
Parname = wc.Range("B1")
```